# How to detect `Active Scheme` of an Xcode project/workspace from command line

Tags: xcode, xcode-project, xcodeproj

There're always more than one (xc)schemes in a single Xcode project/workspace.

When you open a project/workspace with Xcode, Xcode will decide an active scheme as the default scheme to be build/run.

And if you select another scheme, Xcode will remember it and the next time you open the project/workspace again, it will select that scheme to be the default scheme.

But I didn't found where did Xcode store the `Active Scheme` info, nor did I found any API from third party tools like `Xcodeproj` to get the active scheme, only `schemes` provided.

So far I only found in `xx.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/xx.xcuserdatad` the `IDENameString` would change, but is there anything else more robust?